# How to travel safely in Ciudad Juárez, Mexico?

Tags: safety, transportation, mexico

What is the better way to travel safely in Ciudad Juárez, Mexico?
Is it better to rent a car, take the bus or take taxis?

Comment: I may have some prejudices, but I wouldn't associate Ciudad Juárez and safety.

Comment: It is considered a war zone, and it's one of the most dangerous cities in the world. http://urbantitan.com/10-most-dangerous-cities-in-the-world-in-2011/

Comment: @mouviciel yes the title is optimistic

Comment: @vartec: Not to belittle dangers of Ciudad Juárez, but that particular "ranking" is nothing short of arbitrary. Take it with a big grain of salt. (St. Louis is more dangerous than Mogadishu? And in 2012, "the most dangerous city in the world" is Cape Town?)

Comment: I suspect the answer depends on how you define "safety."  Taxis (anywhere in Mexico) are unsafe for your pocket book, if you're not very careful and savvy. Buses may provide the lowest chance of bodily harm, but pick pockets may be a problem, etc.

Comment: By safety I mean don't get physically hurt and not been   kidnapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i will recommend you to rent a car, but a small one, a Aveo or some small car

the bus here on mexico are called "peseras" and they are a mess really mess, you will get lose if you don't know the routes

also taxis on cd juarez and other big citys in mexico are "chocolate" cars that means they are not in line and most of the time the drivers are connected with the drug dealers, so yea pick a gps and rent a car and everything will be fine

Sorry bad english